# What does "clear data" in application settings do?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have added below a screenshot I took of the app settings page. I want to know what the **clear data** and the **force stop** will do to my app?

Specifically, if my app has stored data into a file (I'm making a game and I want to store the progress) and the user presses any one of those buttons, especially **clear data**, I want to know if my file will be deleted and all the progress of the user in the game will be lost.

If I have stored my files in internal storage, will this happen? If so, should I use external storage? And what about `SharedPreferences`?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

on cleardata all internal data of the app will be lost,sharedprefrences,intenal files,database but the data saved on the external storage will remain.So i will advise you to store your data on external storage.

Comment: Files stored in `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` are removed upon uninstall (or clicking the "Clear Data" button), even though they are stored on external storage. Other locations on external storage, such as `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, will not be affected by an uninstall or clicking "Clear Data".