# Storing data in FLASH in android

Tags: android

### Files can be stored in Internal memory or SD-CARD as cache or files

1. If the data is stored as file that file will exist until that is
   explicitly deleted by user
2. If the data is stored as cache, if the android feels that there is
   no memory in phone as a housekeeping operation it clears
   automatically the cache memory

***My Question:***

So assume my app has written a file to SD-CARD or internal memory as a file, now i uninstall my app. will that file also be deleted or will it remain there even after the application is deleted

### {Edit}

**Additional question:** 
when i go to settings screen and do clear cache .... will all the files and cache is automatically deleted created by user of that app w.r.t `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()` and `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Files can be stored in Internal memory or SD-CARD as cache or files

[Internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) have options for cache directories. [Removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), to the extent it is accessible via the Android SDK, does not.

> So assume my app has written a file to SD-CARD or internal memory as a file, now i uninstall my app. will that file also be deleted or will it remain there even after the application is deleted

- Internal storage: your file is deleted
- External storage: if you wrote your file to a location rooted at `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`, your file is deleted. If you wrote your file elsewhere (e.g., `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`), your file is not deleted
- Removable storage, prior to Android 4.4: removable storage is not officially accessible; if your file winds up out there, it should not be deleted when your app is uninstalled
- Removable storage, Android 4.4+: AFAIK, if you write to a supported location (`getExternalFilesDirs()` or `getExternalCacheDirs()`), your file is deleted if that particular bit of removable storage is in the device at the time of uninstall

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info ... if i am clear, if i add a `file` to `removable storage` in any of the `prior android-4.4` it will not be deleted. This statement is valid even if i use `getExternalFilesDir()` or 'getExternalCacheDir()' ?

Comment: @Devrath: `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` are for external storage, not removable storage. With regards to the "Clear Data" button, the effect is as if the user uninstalled and reinstalled your app. Anything that would be deleted when an app is uninstalled would be deleted when the user clicks "Clear Data".

Comment: Now i understand clearly, External storage is the internal storage provided in android(not the RAM) ....... removable storage is SD-card .... so the data on `SD-CARD` is also deleted when i use `clear data` on `Settings` ? ... I was reading another SO-Post - don't know whether its referring correct or misleading(http://stackoverflow.com/a/24927591/1083093). have a look to it !

Comment: @Devrath: "so the data on SD-CARD is also deleted when i use clear data on Settings ?" -- please see the third and fourth bullets in my answer. Anything that would be deleted when an app is uninstalled would be deleted when the user clicks "Clear Data".

Answer (score 1):

I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` to find the user's external SD and write data files to a directory there created for my app. This directory and its contents persist through multiple test re-ininstallations of my app, so I'd say files created in this manner are persistent.

According to [the Android docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) that is not the case for internal storage accessed like this:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

These files would not persist through re-installation.

Comment: There is no `getExternalStorage()` method, and it does not point to "the user's SD" on the vast majority of Android devices.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Edited command after looking at my code. I assumed puts files on the external SD, but I'll defer to CommonsWare on that.